# "There are no Facebook accounts configured" error message on iOS when use IS logged in via Settings - app built with Corona SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, lua, coronasdk

One of our users is getting the following error when they try to post from the native popup:

*No Facebook account.

There are no Facebook accounts configured. You can add or create a Facebook account in Settings.*

However they assure me that they *are* signed into Facebook via Settings, and they are still able to post from one of our other apps. All other test users can post directly without any issues, and afaik it worked in the past in this app for the user who is currently experiencing problems.

It seems like it's most likely an OS issue rather than an issue in my code, I simply request that the native popup be shown and pass an image and some text through (these are still being pushed to the native popup correctly):

```
if native.canShowPopup( "social", "facebook" ) and system.getInfo("platformName") ~= "Android" then

local function socialFBListener(e)
    if e.action == "sent" then
        print("FB post sent successfully")
    end
end

local options = {
    service = "facebook",
    message = "Here is some testing text",
    listener = socialFBListener,
    image = {
        { filename = "testImage.jpg", baseDir = system.DocumentsDirectory },
    },
    url = "http://quixtix.co",
}
native.showPopup( "social", options )

end
```

I can't find any reference to anyone receiving this error when they are signed in, all links I could find simply tell you how to sign in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error was due to a fault on the user's device. After updating iOS and restarting the device the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

> I have the same problem. But its due to I was forgot to set my app as
>   'Public'

it can be done by,

1. Goto https://developers.facebook.com -> App Review
2. Set Make 'appName' public? to YES.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who are struggling with this issue at the moment, the solutions are worked out like this:

1. Delete the Facebook account at iOS "Settings".
2. Try to connect with your Facebook account at your app again.
3. Get success
4. Add the Facebook account back to iOS "Settings" again if you'd like.

Cheers.